# Highcharts and NPM/Node

Tags: highcharts

I am trying to get Highcharts working with Node/Puppeteer.  Edited - just not able to get highcharts recognized by Node script.

```
var Highcharts = require('highcharts');
var fs = require('fs')
var puppeteer = require('puppeteer')

console.log('Highcharts.version=' + Highcharts.version)
console.log('fs W_OK=' + fs.W_OK)
console.log('Puppeteer preferred revision=' + puppeteer._launcher._preferredRevision)
```

Output:

```
Highcharts.version=undefined
fs W_OK=2
Puppeteer preferred revision=624492
```

Had installed highcharts via:

```
npm install -g highcharts
```

Comment: Can you share more of your code where you are trying to use it? Usually the context inside the browser is different than the node context.

Comment: This seems to be either an issue with the highcharts module itself, or the way I installed it with npm.  I edited my original post to add a slimmed down code sample. 
 Tried this on both Mac and Windows with the same result.  Or, perhaps highcharts won't load outside of a browser environment.

Comment: You are installing Highcharts outside browser context and trying to use it inside the browser?

Answer (score 0):

My issue with this simple script was not understanding npm install.  I finally got my script to find 'highcharts' and see the version, though I had to do Highcharts().version instead of Highcharts.version.  My misunderstanding had to do with installing locally or globally when installing with NPM.

Comment: This is nowhere related to puppeteer :D

Comment: True, removed the Puppeteer tag and changed the title.